# Get information about internal state of Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service, state

I have a Windows Service that I am writing in .NET C#. The service is going to act as a file processor. It just watches a directory for File Created events and adds these files to a queue for processing. A separate thread pulls files from the queue and processes them.

My question is whether there is a way to query the windows service to get its "state". I would like to be able to query the service some way and see a list of the files currently waiting in the queue etc.

I know this can be done in Linux via the /proc file system and I was wondering if there is anything similar for Windows. Any tips/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) - It seems like you could simply connect and store this information in a DB, or provide an HttpListener to respond to a connect event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a non-UI method (eg to write the names to a file or to standard output), it is possible to use the ExecuteCommand Method on the service.

```
  ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("ServiceName");
  sc.ExecuteCommand(255);
```

This simply passes this command to your your service and your service will handle it via the OnCustomCommand

```
protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
{
  base.OnCustomCommand(command);
  if (command == 255
  {
      ... // Your code here
  }
}
```

You may need to store your queue/service status in a static variable so you can access it from the OnCustomCommand routine.

Comment: Perfect. This non-UI method was exactly what I was looking for. More info about it here.

http://arcanecode.com/2007/05/30/windows-services-in-c-sending-commands-to-your-windows-service-part-7/

Answer (score 2):

You could create a hosted WCF service inside of the windows service with whatever methods you need to access the state.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

Comment: I gave sgmoore credit for my question because his was more what I was looking for. Although if I have time I might explore yours as well. Thanks for the direction. I did not know all this was possible with Windows Services

Answer (score 0):

WCF would be good to do that, especially it can be hosted inside of Windows Service. Might be in your case it makes sense to use [XML-RPC with WCF](http://vasters.com/clemensv/PermaLink,guid,679ca50b-c907-4831-81c4-369ef7b85839.aspx)